# How to mock x-date-pickers from mui in jest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, material-ui

I added a DateTimePicker to my app which seems to work, however, I'm unable to mock the picker in my Jest tests.

I keep getting the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , _material.generateUtilityClasses) is not a function

       7 | import type { Property, EnumProperty } from "../../types";
    >  8 | import { DateTimePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker";
         | ^
       9 | import { DateTime } from "luxon";

 at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/node/internals/components/PickersToolbarText.js:32:54)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/node/DateTimePicker/DateTimePickerToolbar.js:20:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/node/DesktopDateTimePicker/DesktopDateTimePicker.js:20:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/node/DesktopDateTimePicker/index.js:13:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/node/DateTimePicker/DateTimePicker.js:22:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/node/DateTimePicker/index.js:13:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/myFile/myFile.tsx:8:1)
```

I've tried each of the following, but can't get jest to detect the mock.

```
jest.mock("@mui/x-date-pickers", () => require("../../../__mocks__/x-date-pickers"));
jest.mock("@mui/x-date-pickers", () => (
    <div>
        Hello
    </div>
));
jest.mock("@mui/x-date-pickers");
```

Below is the line throwing the error. It's just a regular import statement:

```
import { DateTimePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker";
```

My mocked file at the location "../../../**mocks**/x-date-pickers" relative to the unit test file. I'm not expecting the mock to work yet, but I'm at least expecting it to be picked up.

```
import React from "react";
import { DateTimePickerProps } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";

export const DateTimePicker = (props: DateTimePickerProps) => (
    <input
        data-testid="mockedDateField"
        onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            props.onChange(event.target.value);
        }}
    />
);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: (0 , \_material.generateUtilityClasses) is not a function when trying to mock x-date-pickers in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121199/typeerror-0-material-generateutilityclasses-is-not-a-function-when-trying)

Comment: lol I posted that yesterday and it didn't get any answers so I posted this one today.

Comment: Sorry, the canned comment isn't useful in this use case - the point is not to re-post, but _edit_ the previous post if you have more information.

Comment: That's fair. I didn't have additional information, it was more rephrasing so I could get more eyes on it, but I found the issue. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: Then please delete the previous iteration at least, otherwise it just hangs around unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I needed to add DateTimePicker to the end of my mock:

```
jest.mock("@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker", () => require("../../../__mocks__/x-date-pickers"));
```